# PySpark: fully cleaning checkpoints

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

According the [documentation](https://people.apache.org/~pwendell/spark-nightly/spark-master-docs/latest/configuration.html) is possible to tell Spark to keep track of *"out of scope"* checkpoints - those that are not needed anymore - and clean them from disk.

```py
SparkSession.builder
  ...
  .config("spark.cleaner.referenceTracking.cleanCheckpoints", "true")
  .getOrCreate()
```

Apparently it does so but the problem, however, is that the last checkpointed rdds are never deleted.

### Question

- Is there any configuration I am missing to perform all cleanse?
- If there isn't: Is there any way to get the name of the temporary folder created for a particular application so I can programatically delete it? I.e. Get `0c514fb8-498c-4455-b147-aff242bd7381` from `SparkContext` the same way you can get the `applicationId`

Comment: I've filed [SPARK-33000](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-33000) over the misleading behavior of this `cleanCheckpoints` config.

Answer (score 13):

I know its old question but recently i was exploring on `checkpoint` and had similar problems. Would like to share the findings.

> Question :Is there any configuration I am missing to perform all cleanse?

Setting `spark.cleaner.referenceTracking.cleanCheckpoints=true` is working sometime but its hard to rely on it. official document says that by setting this property

> clean checkpoint files if the reference is out of scope

I don't know what exactly it means because my understanding is once spark session/context is stopped it should clean it.

***However***, I found a answer to your below question

> If there isn't: Is there any way to get the name of the temporary
>   folder created for a particular application so I can programatically
>   delete it? I.e. Get 0c514fb8-498c-4455-b147-aff242bd7381 from
>   SparkContext the same way you can get the applicationId

**Yes**, We can get the `checkpointed` directory like below:

**Scala :**

```
//Set directory
scala> spark.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir("hdfs:///tmp/checkpoint/")

scala> spark.sparkContext.getCheckpointDir.get
res3: String = hdfs://<name-node:port>/tmp/checkpoint/625034b3-c6f1-4ab2-9524-e48dfde589c3

//It gives String so we can use org.apache.hadoop.fs to delete path
```

**PySpark:**

```
// Set directory
>>> spark.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir('hdfs:///tmp/checkpoint')
>>> t = sc._jsc.sc().getCheckpointDir().get()
>>> t 
u'hdfs://<name-node:port>/tmp/checkpoint/dc99b595-f8fa-4a08-a109-23643e2325ca'

// notice 'u' at the start which means It returns unicode object
// Below are the steps to get hadoop file system object and delete

>>> fs = sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration())
fs.exists(sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(str(t)))
True

>>> fs.delete(sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(str(t)))
True
```

Answer (score -2):

In Scala, without filesystem you can use below code to delete any hdfs directory

scala> s"hdfs dfs -rmr checkpoint-directory-path" !