# Automatically delete checkpoint files in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm creating spark context and session in my PySpark code like this,

```
conf = SparkConf().set("spark.cleaner.referenceTracking.cleanCheckpoints", "true")
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=conf)

spark = SparkSession(sc)
spark.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir("../../checkpoints")
```

In my code that follows I'm using `checkpoint()` over some dataframes. It works as expected.

But I want to remove the checkpoints after the code is run to completion.

Is there a spark configuration that I can use? `cleanCheckpoints` is not doing that.

How can I delete those checkpoint files when the code is completed? What is the best approach?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60009856/877069 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/52630858/877069

Answer (score 0):

Write any cleanup logic inside `onApplicationStart` or `onApplicationEnd` method of `SparkListener`
& take look at `SparkListener` abstract class for other useful methods.

`Note`: Below `scala` code shows how to register SparkLister & access methods.

```
spark.sparkContext.addSparkListener(new SparkListener() {

  override def onApplicationStart(applicationStart: SparkListenerApplicationStart) {
    println("Spark ApplicationStart: " + applicationStart.appName);
  }
  override def onApplicationEnd(applicationEnd: SparkListenerApplicationEnd) {
    println("Spark ApplicationEnd: " + applicationEnd.time);
  }
});
```

Comment: How can I do this in PySpark?

Comment: This post will help you to achieve same - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44082957/how-to-add-a-sparklistener-from-pyspark-in-python

Comment: I think it's bit complex to do same in python..:)